# How to hide a column in a bootstrap table?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2015

In my ASP.NET MVC Core app that uses Bootstrap (installed by default by Visual Studio 2015 MVC Core project), I need to use ID column in a controller but want to hide it in the View. But the following `View` still displays the column as blank. I would like to hide the first columns that is the ID column

**View**:

```
@model List<myProj.Models.StateName>

<form id="target" asp-controller="TestController" asp-action="TestAction" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData[" ReturnUrl"]" method="post">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>
                    State Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    State Code
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
            {
            <tr>
                <td><input asp-for="@Model[i].StateId" type="hidden" /></td>
                <td>
                    <label asp-for="@Model[i].State"></label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input asp-for="@Model[i].StateCode" type="text" readonly style="border:0px;"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Add `style="visibility: hidden"`

Comment: Or you can add attribute `style="display: none"` in both `<td>` and `<th>`

Comment: @Div `style="visibility:hidden"` does not quite work. I've just added an UPDATE section to my post.

Comment: @ArasuRRK `style="display:none"` does not quite work. I've just added an UPDATE section to my post.

Comment: @Div No. I've tried, e.g., `<th style="visibility:hidden"></th>` and <td style="visibility:hidden"><input asp-for="@Model[i].StateId" type="hidden" /></td>`.

Comment: @nam Try `<input asp-for="@Model[i].StateId" type="hidden" style="visibility:hidden"/>`

Comment: @Div I tried that but to no avail.

Comment: @ArasuRRK What you are probably suggesting is what the user `Chris Pratt` showed below - and it works (thank you).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested the behavior you describe in this [pen](http://codepen.io/chrisdpratt/pen/amKpXy). The "Bad Table" version demonstrates what I believe you are likely seeing and occurs by neglecting to add `display:none` to one single `th`/`td` in that column. The "Good Table" version has the first column completely hidden and stretches to fill the entire available width.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<h2>Good Table</h2>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="display:none">Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Column 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="display:none">Data 1.1</td>
            <td>Data 1.2</td>
            <td>Data 1.3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="display:none">Data 2.1</td>
            <td>Data 2.2</td>
            <td>Data 2.3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="display:none">Data 3.1</td>
            <td>Data 3.2</td>
            <td>Data 3.3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<h2>Bad Table</h2>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="display:none">Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Column 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="display:none">Data 1.1</td>
            <td>Data 1.2</td>
            <td>Data 1.3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Data 2.1</td> <!-- WHOOPS -->
            <td>Data 2.2</td>
            <td>Data 2.3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="display:none">Data 3.1</td>
            <td>Data 3.2</td>
            <td>Data 3.3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Long and short, check the rendered output and ensure that each `th`/`td` in the column you are hiding ended up with the `display:none` style.